# Unmount btrfs subvolume from tree

Tags: linux, mount, btrfs

On an btrfs volume, I have a folder `snapshots/` in which I store a snapshot of the whole volume from time to time.

btrfs automatically mounts all subvolumes, eg. after mounting the top volume, `snapshots/` is populated with all snapshots ever done.

Now I like to unmount the subvolumes in `snapshots`, leaving `snapshots` empty (without deleting the snapshots of course). This is very useful if I do backups, indexing or searching on the volume, which otherwise always needs to be limited in a tool-dependent fashion to exclude `snapshots/`, which is not always easy.

As the subvolumes are not mounted by kernel, I cannot unmount them with `mount`. How to unmount them?

Comment: Compare this question: [*btrfs: browsing subvolumes*](https://superuser.com/q/1396245/432690).

Answer (score 0):

You can [organize your btrfs volumes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Btrfs#Subvolumes) in a different way to avoid this automatic mount (by not mounting btrfs `/` onto your system `/` but a btrfs subvolume like `/rootfs` onto your system `/` instead. Only btrfs subvolumes named `/rootfs/foo/bar` will be auto-mounted as `/foo/bar` in this case). But this is not a very easy task and you can have difficulties to reboot your computer if you fail one step.

As an umount workaround, the easier way in my opinion is to hide the content of you `snapshot` subvol my mounting a dumb mountpoint over it. You can automate this through your fstab like this:

```
none    /snapshot   tmpfs   defaults,size=1M,ro 0 0
```

To access your `/snapshot` subvol again, an easy way is to add a specific non-automatic mountpoint (read-only in this example because your rarely need to alter our snapshots):

```
/dev/sda2   /mnt/snapshots  btrfs   defaults,noauto,ro,subvol=/snapshot 0 2
```

Note:
You can also simply not hide your snapshot subvol but set specific safe  mount options for it:

```
/dev/sda2   /snapshots  btrfs   defaults,noexec,nodev,ro,subvol=/snapshot   0 2
```

Comment: Reboot is not an issue, as my `btrfs` volumes are not containing my root fs.