# Weird directories after installing any two Linux distros

Tags: linux, grub, btrfs, initramfs-tools

When I install any Linux distro, I'm always successful now. But that only happens if I install one distro, and I dual boot Windows and usually Linux Mint. I decided to branch out into Arch, and I saw that when I installed it with pacstrap and mounted my Linux Mint root partition, there was an /@/ and /@home/ directory. The /@home/ directory was empty, while the /@/ directory seemed to contain my root filesystem. I'm using btrfs on all my filesystems. The same problem was also there on my Arch system. I deleted Arch after, and tried to reinstall GRUB. I got dumped into a GRUB command prompt. Using the GRUB terminal, I attempted to load the kernel manually and boot Linux Mint; this dropped me into an initramfs BusyBox shell saying that /root/dev and a few other crucial directories like /bin, /sbin, /dev, and others didn't exist. I eventually had to salvage my Linux Mint data and delete Linux Mint and only use Windows. The exact same thing happens when I install any two distros. How can I stop OS installers from dumping the contents of another filesystem into these mysterious /@/ and /@home/ directories?

Comment: Did you try installing two linux distributions into the same partition? They should have their own partitions, and shouldn't be overwriting each others files like that. Getting only GRUB working with both shouldn't be too difficult, but this doesn't sound like just a grub entry problem

Comment: No, I didn't install them on the same partition. I attempted to install Ubuntu Studio without a bootloader, and it seemed to work. But the same thing happened to my Linux Mint partition.

Comment: Some distros, when installed on Btrfs, use `@` and `@home` *subvolumes* within a single Btrfs filesystem instead of separate filesystems on separate partitions. Any other distro that tries to mount the Btrfs filesystem *in its entirety* will see these subvolumes as directories and this is normal. Sharing `/boot` (if this is the case) may be a different story and add to the confusion.

Comment: Please see this answer of mine: [btrfs: browsing subvolumes](https://superuser.com/a/1396270/432690). It should shed some light on what this `@` is for.