# BTRFS discrepancy between df and du

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, du, df

the difference between disk usage reported by `df` and `du` makes 20% of capacity of my drive. It is ubuntu-type btrfs filesystem with @ and @home. Where could be the problem please?

```
df -h /dev/sda2
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       112G   68G   43G  62% /
```

`sda2` partition is mounted to `/run/timeshift/backup`

```
sudo du -h -d 0 /run/timeshift/backup
48G /run/timeshift/backup
```

Where is the difference of 20GB?

On other disk:

```
janbenes@Tablet4 ~ (master)> sudo btrfs filesystem du -s /run/timeshift/backup/@
     Total   Exclusive  Set shared  Filename
 678.45GiB   305.54MiB   678.15GiB  /run/timeshift/backup/@
janbenes@Tablet4 ~ (master)> sudo btrfs filesystem du -s /run/timeshift/backup/@home
     Total   Exclusive  Set shared  Filename
 175.53GiB   168.46MiB   175.36GiB  /run/timeshift/backup/@home
janbenes@Tablet4 ~ (master)> sudo btrfs filesystem df /run/timeshift/backup
Data, single: total=1.45TiB, used=1.02TiB
System, single: total=4.00MiB, used=240.00KiB
Metadata, single: total=11.01GiB, used=6.77GiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=512.00MiB, used=0.00B
```

According to `btrfs filesystem du` used capacity should be about 850GB and not 1,020GB.

Comment: Probably [this](https://superuser.com/a/1396270/432690). Take this into account and still there are other factors (did you `btrfs balance` recently?). Take them into account and still [`df` and `du` are different *in general*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120311/108618); plus there are `btrfs filesystem du` and `btrfs filesystem df`.

Comment: hello. Tried ```btrfs filesystem``` on another disk and still huge difference. I have seen it before. Looks like BTRFS comes at cost of 20% capacity of a disk...