# Non-empty mount points with btrfs (SLES15): Are they needed?

Tags: mount, btrfs, suse

I have many years of UNIX experience, but I think i made a fatal mistake:

Seeing messages during boot about non-empty mount points, I took the chance to clean them up while migration a system to a new environment.
I booted the SLES Rescue System, mounted the root filesystem and the basic system structure (proc, sys, dev) on `/mnt`, then did `chroot /mnt` and `mount -va`.

So everything looked nice, I adjusted some configuration settings and while unmounting I checked the mount points.
For example:
`/var/cache` was mounted, `umount` succeeded, but still `ll /var/cache` showed a non-empty mount point while the filesystem was displayed not mounted.
So I removed the contents.

Basically I repeated the steps for every filesystem mounted, then left the `chroot` environment, umounted the rest and rebooted.

Unfortunately the system won't boot as GRUB complained it cannot find `normal.mod`.

So is this a feature of btrfs subvolumes?
Who can explain what was going on?

### `/etc/fstab`

As I was asked for `/etc/fstab`, here is what a typical system has:

```fstab
/dev/sys/root                              /            btrfs  defaults              0  0
/dev/sys/root                              /var         btrfs  subvol=/@/var         0  0
/dev/sys/root                              /usr/local   btrfs  subvol=/@/usr/local   0  0
/dev/sys/root                              /tmp         btrfs  subvol=/@/tmp         0  0
/dev/sys/root                              /srv         btrfs  subvol=/@/srv         0  0
/dev/sys/root                              /root        btrfs  subvol=/@/root        0  0
/dev/sys/root                              /opt         btrfs  subvol=/@/opt         0  0
UUID=9fd27493-d194-48ba-a4bc-3551123e0d3b  /home        xfs    defaults              0  0
/dev/sys/boot                              /boot        btrfs  defaults              0  0
UUID=0092-D1D5                             /boot/efi    vfat   utf8                  0  2
/dev/sys/root                              /.snapshots  btrfs  subvol=/@/.snapshots  0  0
```

Comment: Without seeing your `fstab` I can only guess (so not an answer). Suppose there is a subvolume named `boot`. Suppose you mount `subvol=/whatever` as `/` and then `subvol=/whatever/boot` as `/boot/`. If you `umount` `/boot` then you will still see its content – not as a mounted subvolume but as a subvolume that exists under `/whatever` in the Btrfs subvolume tree (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1396270/432690) if this is confusing to you). This is a possible scenario where files in `/boot` are the same regardless if `/boot` is mounted.

Comment: As I has such experience before, I suspect `systemd` silently remounting the filesystem, so I did not clean up the mountpoint (as expected), but cleaned the actual mounted filesystem. Unfortunately I cannot prove any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How it worked

`/dev/sys/root` contains a Btrfs filesystem. Several entries in your `fstab` mount different subvolumes of it to different mountpoints.

**Hypothesis: the default subvolume in the Btrfs filesystem in `/dev/sys/root` is `/@` and once it's mounted at `/`, mounting many other subvolumes *at their particular mount points* makes little to no sense because the right (and usually non-empty) directories are already where you expect them.**

(To see the default subvolume, run `sudo btrfs subvolume get-default /`.)

Please read [this another answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1396270/432690) and understand the conceptual difference between the Btrfs directory (and subvolumes) tree on a device and the directory structure in your OS. Without this knowledge the rest of the current answer may be very confusing to you.

*If the default subvolume is `/@`*, `/@` from the Btrfs tree appears as `/` in the OS tree *along with everything beneath*. This mounting *alone* is enough to see e.g. the directory `/@/var` from the Btrfs tree as `/var` in the OS tree. I mean if you try to access `/var` *before* `/var` is mounted then

- the OS will check if `/var` (of the OS) is a mountpoint; it's not;
- so the OS will check if `/` (of the OS) is a mountpoint; it is and it's associated with `/@` of the Btrfs;
- so the OS will show you `/@/var` of the Btrfs as `/var` of the OS.

It so happens `/@/var` of the Btrfs is a subvolume. *Additionally* mounting `subvol=/@/var` at `/var` (of the OS) will make the same directory appear as `/var` (of the OS). Specifically, if you now access `/var` then

- the OS will check if `/var` (of the OS) is a mountpoint; it is and it's associated with `/@/var` of the Btrfs;
- so the OS will show you `/@/var` of the Btrfs.

And if you unmount `/var` (of the OS) then you will go back to the first case.

So it doesn't matter if `/var` (of the OS) is mounted or not (virtually it doesn't matter, there may be subtleties). One way or another you will see `/@/var` of the Btrfs as `/var` in the OS.

Several other entries in your `fstab` mount different subvolumes *where you would see them anyway*. I don't really see the point of these entries (some subtlety I cannot identify at the moment may be the point; or these entries are totally pointless indeed).

For comparison: if `/var` (of the OS) was mounted with `subvol=/var` then mounting it would make sense because `/var` of the Btrfs is not under `/@` of the Btrfs and thus you cannot reach it just by mounting `/@` of the Btrfs as `/` of the OS.

---

#### How you broke it

> … was mounted, `umount` succeeded, but still `ll …` showed a non-empty mount point while the filesystem was displayed not mounted. So I removed the contents.

As I said, several entries in your `fstab` mount different subvolumes where you would see them anyway. In these cases by removing the contents after `umount` you removed the contents you saw before `umount`. You thought you removed shadowed, irrelevant contents, but actually you removed the actual, important contents.

There are two things that don't fit though:

1. Your example mountpoint is `/var/cache`, you allegedly unmounted it; but there is no `/var/cache` in the `fstab` you posted.
2. According you the `fstab` you posted, while `/` (of the OS) comes from `/dev/sys/root`, `/boot` (of the OS) comes from `/dev/sys/boot`. The described mechanism of breaking things cannot apply. Yet you claim that "GRUB complained it cannot find `normal.mod`" and from this I deduce you did break things under `/boot` somehow.

Therefore I suspect the published `fstab` (you described it as "what a typical system has") is not the *exact* `fstab` of the affected OS. I suspect `/boot` there used the same filesystem as `/`, was unnecessarily mounted and thus prone to the described scenario of breaking things.

Comment: For the fstab I wrote: "here is what a typical system has" So it was not the original fstab. I can only speculate: Possibly I reinstalled the system before you asked for the fstab (as the system was ruined significantly).