# False disk usage report on a btrfs root partition

Tags: linux, filesystems, arch-linux, btrfs, manjaro

I checked my disk usage using `btrfs filesystem df /` and it shows high disk usage like so [image]

However I am 100% certain that I actually use 72.8GB as shown on filelight. I tried `sudo btrfs balance start -m /` and removing snapshots to no avail, I'm running Manjaro on the latest kernel.

What can I do to fix this?
Thanks :)

Comment: Make sure you're aware of the content of the *entire* filesystem. [Example](https://superuser.com/a/1396270/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski What do you mean by "being aware of the filesystem"?

Comment: Have you read the linked answer? What you see in `/` in your OS may be some subvolume, not the whole Btrfs filesystem. If you don't see the whole filesystem then it's natural you think it contains less data.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I read it, though I'm confused by what I see. timeshift-btrfs directory usage shows 144GB, '@home' is 67GB and '@' is 76.9GB, togather it's a greater usage than my entire SSD...

Comment: (1) "Usage shows" is meaningless, unless you tell us [what exact command you used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120311/108618). (2) `timeshift-btrfs` probably contains snapshots that share disk space with other subvolumes. Useful command: `btrfs filesystem du -s *`. Exclusive content from `timeshift-btrfs` along with `@` and `@home` may result in 167 GiB in question.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Oh I see, timeshift-btrfs shares everything with `@` and `@home` which is why it seems as if I use double the disk space (correct?). But what will happen when I'll try to create a file that's greater than the falsely reported (by dolphine for example) free disk space?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Here's a photo of the output https://i.imgur.com/RM5PuvQ.png

Comment: It's not falsely reported. The snapshots share some data between them and between the current data, but there are also parts that aren't shared. All of that adds up to 167 GiB.

Comment: Yeah... Theres nothing wrong here.

Comment: do df in a folder

Comment: Some problem. > LANG=C df -h /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p4   90G   85G  4.7G  95%  . Filelight shown / has only 20 GiB used

Comment: It seems filelight does not deal (omitting) btrfs subvolumes, treating it as mounted filesystem. It makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I figured it, because of BTRFSs concept of "free space", programs like filelight fail to report the correct usage, and in fact, I do use space as `btrfs fi df /` reports.
For example, here's dolphin report
[image]