# How to hide files inside linux operating system folders

Tags: linux

I need to hide files inside Linux system folders, and there are system folders that are large enough for hiding these files, but I'm afraid of causing issues in the OS if I forcefully move my files into folders within system folders:

```
/bin      /cdrom    /etc      /opt      /run      /srv    /tmp    /var
/boot     /dev      /home     /proc     /snap     /sys    /usr    etc...
```

How can I create arbitrary folders inside the aforementioned system folders, moving my files into them?

Comment: Unless you are replacing files you should be fine, obviously, it’s not recommended practice.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  The answer might give us a better option than what you are thinking of doing

Comment: `/proc` and `/sys` are virtual filesystems and you cannot create arbitrary files there. In `/dev` you can, but you don't want to, it's in RAM and re-created on reboot. `/run` may be similar in this matter. `/tmp` may or may not be in RAM, but even if it's not, it may be cleaned up on a regular basis.

Comment: @Keltari to hide files

Comment: From whom? Storing anything inside system directories requires root access; so you are root, right? Files in `/root` cannot be accessed by non-root users, this is an obvious place where root can "hide" something from regular users. Or do you want to hide files from *another* person with root access?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I am the root, hiding it from myself under duress

Comment: What happens when, under duress, you are forced to give up the root pw?

Comment: `/bin` and `/sbin` are notoriously bad places to hide things, because the shell actively suggests the names of anything in there.

Comment: @SimonRichter: If by "actively suggest" you mean command completion, it only functions if the file is marked executable.

Comment: @Russo -- that's why plausible deniability is incorporated into systems like Veracrypt. You'd be better off using tried and tested solutions than to try to come up with new ones. Its help describes how to do it.

Comment: In a nutshell, there is *nowhere* on the linux filesystem you can 'hide' files that a user with root privileges that knows to look for them can't `find` them. I recommend full-disk encryption instead.

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: I second what @Shadur said. Full-disk encryption or just file encryption is practically the tried and tested way to "hide" files from other people.

Comment: And if this question is about cryptographic currencies, your best bet would be a dedicated hardware wallet.

Comment: @FreeMan Agreed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> I'm afraid of causing issues in the OS if I forcefully move my files into folders within system folders:

There is no such thing as "forcefully move", exactly. If by force you mean bypassing file permissions with "sudo", that's not necessarily the cause of the issues you might have – there might be side effects from files merely *being* in a certain place, not from the way they got there.

(That aside, you're not really "forcing" anything if root is the one who has permission to write into those locations in the first place, if you take a look at the directory permissions.)

A regular `mkdir` should be fine (as root), as long as you keep in mind that not all folders you listed are identical (that is, not all of them are normal directories on disk).

Things to consider before doing this:

- What are you hiding, who are you hiding it from, and whose system are you hiding it in? For example, if the system has etckeeper installed to track changes to /etc, storing a large file there would be the exact opposite of hiding it.

  Server administrators might be using tools that specifically alert on "hidden" files (e.g. `/root/.foo`) as that's often a sign of malware infection – that's where you find cryptominers. Other forensics tools will search the entire disk for "interesting" files regardless of location.
- Is the folder in question actually on your *disk*? Not everything in the filesystem is a disk location – certain locations have virtual filesystems mounted on them (which you can see in `findmnt`). For example, `/sys` has sysfs on it, which is entirely virtual and you can't really put arbitrary things in it. Several directories you listed are 'tmpfs' mounts, where you *can* put arbitrary files – but tmpfs contents disappear on reboot.

  Look at `findmnt` and/or `df -h` and confirm that the location you've chosen is part of the main `/` filesystem and not a virtual filesystem.
- Will you be changing permissions of the folder itself? Will you change them back? (What effect will it have? Will you accidentally lock yourself out of /bin/chmod after chmod'ing /bin the wrong way?)

  To avoid the need to change permissions of an existing location, only use root (sudo) privileges to create a subfolder and change the permissions of that, so that everything else can be done unprivileged.

  Try to keep a spare "root" terminal (or two) open when doing large changes. That is, not just a terminal where you run `sudo`, but a terminal where you have started a *shell* as root, using `sudo -i` or `sudo bash`. Several kinds of changes (such as accidentally moving /lib elsewhere) are easier to undo that way.
- Will you overwrite something with your files (e.g. in case of wrong tab-completion)?

  Always use the `mv -i` option to enable confirmation before anything is overwritten by accident.
- Will your new files or folders cause *future* conflicts with something that might be created by the system, e.g. installed from packages in the future?

  (As an example, if you "hide" something at /dev/sdc – putting aside the issue of /dev being a tmpfs – what will happen when you connect a USB stick and it too gets the name 'sdc'?)

  This isn't necessarily a big problem, but it means you'll need to *remember* what you did to the system.
- Will your new files or folders be accidentally picked up by the OS? In some locations, any file with a certain filename will be automatically read; e.g. GRUB will look for any `/boot/vmlinuz*` file, so in the *best* case, if you try to hide something at /boot/vmlinuz-homework, GRUB will start complaining about unrecognized formats and make the file's presence very obvious. In the worst case, a service might stop working because it found a "config" and doesn't understand it.

  There is no single way to recognize such locations, but avoid putting random things in `*.d/` folders in particular (e.g. many services try to load e.g. `something.d/*.conf`).

Answer (score 32):

There exist products that are made for hiding files, which are better
than invented methods.

For example, you could use
[VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/code/VeraCrypt/),
described as:

> VeraCrypt is a software for establishing and maintaining an on-the-fly-encrypted volume (data storage device). On-the-fly encryption means that data is automatically encrypted right before it is saved and decrypted right after it is loaded, without any user intervention. No data stored on an encrypted volume can be read (decrypted) without using the correct password/keyfile(s) or correct encryption keys. Entire file system is encrypted (e.g., file names, folder names, contents of every file, free space, meta data, etc).

The VeraCrypt volume when mounted appears to be a separate
disk. Externally it can appear to be a single binary file which
is totally unreadable, meaning looks like random garbage.

In an extreme case, a VeraCrypt volume can hide inside unallocated
space on the disk, so is totally invisible.

Mounting the VeraCrypt volume requires that, first, someone know
beforehand what it is, and, second, that this someone know the
volume password (or phrase-key).

Answer (score 10):

What you are asking implies that you have root access.
It also implies that there is at least one other person with root access that you are trying to hide from.
It also implies that you are not a particularly sophisticated user.

So, I have one question for you...

Are you prepared to lose access to all the computers on your site, be kicked out of school, lose your job, and possibly go to jail for what you are going to do?

Because unless you are smarter than all the people providing answers here, you are going to get caught immediately.

For 3 years I was in charge of security for an installation with several hundred govt owned computers. Because management was very paranoid, they asked me to monitor all the computers for attempts to use them outside of mission scope. At that time I already had more than 10 years experience with Linux. That was around 2005.

I wrote scripts that examined file timestamps, magic numbers, new files created in unexpected places, checksums, device lists, logins that did not match existing records, etc. External monitoring detected anomalous port usage and network activity. And because it was my full-time job, they emailed me immediately if anything was detected. They also logged to a remote server.

And I could do that effectively because everyone who could possibly access those computers was vetted. If public access was possible, I would have written a kernel module instead of scripts.

You have to understand that whereas your Linux system might seem ponderously large and complicated to you, it doesn't appear that way to the people several levels above your pay grade. If it actually matters to somebody that you not play spies on your hardware, you will get smacked down quicker than you would think possible.

Comment: This. What the OP is asking -- and they way they're phrasing their questions -- heavily implies they don't understand *nearly* enough about what they're doing to have any hope of pulling it off successfully, and this is the sort of 'cutesy' bullshit that profoundly irritates the adults in the room who have to clean it up.

Comment: What if your kernel module or scripts do not run?

Answer (score 2):

There's a few tricks you can do.

Remember everything on *nix is a file.

1. Trick #1 mkdir ".. "

```
chris@chriss-MacBook-Pro ~ % mkdir ".. "
chris@chriss-MacBook-Pro ~ % cd ".. "
chris@chriss-MacBook-Pro ..  % touch hi
chris@chriss-MacBook-Pro ..  % cd ..
chris@chriss-MacBook-Pro ~ % ls -al | head -n5
total 5744
drwxr-x---+  66 chris  staff     2112 Sep  7 13:49 .
drwxr-xr-x    5 root   admin      160 May 24  2022 ..
drwxr-xr-x    3 chris  staff       96 Sep  7 13:49 .. 
drwxr-xr-x    7 chris  staff      224 May 29  2022 .3T
chris@chriss-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

You will notice that we created a directory called ".. " notice the extra space in the end. If someone does a directory listing they will easily miss this as it appears as .. which means "go back"

if you want to change to this directory do cd ".. " and you will then be in that directory.

2. Trick #2

```
touch .hi
echo "hi">.hi

ls 

Will not show file hi
ls -la will.
```

3. Trick #3
   Install LUKS or Veracrypt this will password protect and encrypt the folder
4. Trick #4 - install a kernel module or use library interposition (LD_PRELOAD) to hook the system call responsible for cd or ls to not show the contents of the directory.

There's many resources on this online.

Comment: Note that all of these "tricks" will at best only *mildly* slow down an actually competent sysadmin that's looking for shenanigans, and will most likely irritate them. Unless you have a *good* reason (and "playing silly buggers" is not a good reason) I recommend not doing this.

Comment: 100% this is to be done on your own system to avoid casual users of your computer browsing folders with important docs etc, Anywhere else, this would be easily picked up by simple commands like find / -ctime -1. Dont do anything stupid, everything else can be very easily picked up. I had set up a distributed bash shell keylogging system across 500 hosts that logged centrally anything not approved by change window. Good luck..

Comment: Re: "everything is a file:" Depends on how you define a file. "Everything is a file" relies on a potentially surprising definition of a file: a file is anything that is addressable by a filepath. A more expected definition of a file would be: a file is a collection of data stored on a hard drive/SSD/removable media. Anything in `/run`, `/dev`, `/tmp`, `/sys`, `/proc`, or `/boot` will fail to meet this definition.

Comment: @A.R. classic Tanenbaum definition of anything on the FS - "everything is a file" as each object if you will is addressable by an inode, whether its a directory or a file or  or or

Comment: @ChristianPapathanasiou It's an important distinction. `/dev/null`, `/proc/1234`, `/boot/grub`, and `/run/sshd.pid` are four very different things, and none of them is the same as `~/myFile.txt`. For example, `~/myFile.txt` is guaranteed to be finite in size, but `/dev/null` is infinite, and performing regular file operations like `mv` and `rm` on these "files" can have unexpected and deleterious effects on the operating system. If I do `echo "test" > $file; cat $file`, I expect it to print "test". But if `$file` is `/dev/null`, it won't do that.

Comment: Yes @A.R. from a user perspective you are 10,000% correct. From a systems perspective, none of that is relevant however as  everything is simply addressable by its inode and is readable and writable like any other file on the system. I think its one of those forever debates but I think we both have more productive things to get on with :-))

Answer (score 2):

If your main (or whichever) filesystem is Btrfs and if the subvolume you mount is not the root of the filesystem, and if you don't normally mount the root of the filesystem, then you can create "aside" subvolume(s) and store files there. The files won't be available under your regular mountpoint *at all*.

Please read [*btrfs: browsing subvolumes*](https://superuser.com/q/1396245/432690) and my answer there to learn that any Btrfs filesystem has its own directory (and subvolumes) tree and you can easily mount only a part of it.

E.g. suppose `/` of your OS is really `/@` (or `/@rootfs` or so) of your Btrfs filesystem, i.e. it is mounted with `subvol=@` option; and suppose you *don't* normally mount the entire filesystem (with `subvol=/`). Then by actually mounting the entire filesystem somewhere:

```
mount -o subvol=/ /dev/sdx1 /some/mountpoint
```

and creating a subvolume:

```
btrfs subvolume create /some/mountpoint/stash
```

and finally unmounting:

```
umount /some/mountpoint
```

you will create a subvolume `/stash` that is *not* under the subvolume `/@` you use as `/` of your OS. To access your stash you will need to mount the filesystem with `subvol=/stash` (or `subvol=/` to access the entire filesystem again).

This is kinda like having a stash in a filesystem you don't normally mount, but without any need of having a separate filesystem. Adding data to your Btrfs `/stash` will consume free space of the filesystem you're using as `/` in your OS, exactly like hiding something in `/usr` would; so it's similar to what you're asking about. The differences are:

- your stash will not affect the OS in any other way,
- you can easily make the stash disappear from the directory tree of the OS (by unmounting).

Invoking `btrfs subvolume list /` or mounting the entire filesystem will reveal the existence of `stash`, regardless if the `stash` subvolume itself is mounted or not.