# How did this usage of chmod break sudo access?

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, chmod

In many other topics, I have seen people breaking their sudo access with commands such as

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /
```

and variants. Thinking I was doing it right, I have executed the following commands on a server with multiple users and ended up in a disastrous state. Nobody can access their user accounts anymore, and root access is also not working. Here is the first command I executed:

```
cd /mnt/ssd5/Datasets/dataset_1/
sudo chmod 777 . -r
```

I am not sure if this one was the command which broke sudo access. Because afterwards I could do:

```
cd /mnt/ssd5/Datasets/dataset_2/
sudo chmod -R 777 .
```

But this time I did not have to type password. Can somebody see the source of the problem?

Comment: I don't know what was underneath `dataset_1`, but it's unlikely that changing its permissions would affect Linux, unless it contains symbolic links to sensitive Linux folders.

Comment: A symbolic link could be the culprit if `dataset_N` itself is a symbolic link. Symbolic links below `dataset_N/` are most likely safe because `chmod -R` probably does not follow links (I guess it may depend on implementation though). But it's possible to mount the same filesystem (or its parts) to different paths, so it's possible some directory under `/mnt/ssd5/Datasets/dataset_2/` was the same object as your `/`. Compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1396270/432690) where `/mnt/ssd/@` is the same as my `/`. Something similar may work for filesystems other than Btrfs.

Comment: how long was it between invocations? sudo can be configured to only prompt for a password once in a period of time. the default in ubunutu is 15 minutes. https://www.makeuseof.com/change-sudo-password-timeout-linux/ so you run one command with sudo, and two minutes later run a second. the first command will prompt for password, but the second will not.