# How to mount BTRFS partition multiple times both using the same space allocation?

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, mount, btrfs

I’m new to BTRFS and am wondering if it’s possible to share the space of a single partition but mount it under multiple mount points?

For example, I have a 1 TiB partition and want to share the same space for `/home` and for `/var/run/docker` and possibly other mount points. But obviously, the contents of those directories would be different and contain their respective files, and each could grow and shrink to fill the entire 1TiB.

Is this possible to do with BTRFS and sub-volumes? If so, are there any good guides on how to do this?

Comment: I'm not very clued up on BTRFS and I am not sure I understand your question, but why not just use Symlinks?

Comment: You may find this resource useful: [btrfs: browsing subvolumes](https://superuser.com/q/1396245/432690). The main point: "Btrfs directory (and subvolumes) tree on your device is conceptually different than the directory structure in the OS". I wish someone clearly explained this to me when I was new to Btrfs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can already do this without subvolumes, using any filesystem. Mount it at one location, then use `bind` mounts to mount that onto the locations you need. (Bind mounts have equal standing to the initial mount; the result is exactly as if the same filesystem were mounted in multiple places. The initial location could then even be unmounted, though there's no good way to express that through /etc/fstab until very recently.)

```
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/disk

mkdir /mnt/disk/home
mkdir /mnt/disk/vardocker

mount -o bind /mnt/disk/home /home
mount -o bind /mnt/disk/var/docker /var/lib/docker
```

The latter two commands would be /etc/fstab entries with type `none` and options `bind`.

(Hopefully you meant `/var/lib/docker`, as that's where the storage location is, whereas /var/run (now known as /run) is a the opposite of that.)

With a *very* recent 'util-linux' package (and a relatively recent kernel as well), this can be simplified using the `X-mount.subdir=` option which hides the whole mount/bind/unmount dance behind one direct command (or one fstab entry):

```
mount -o X-mount.subdir=home /dev/sda3 /home
mount -o X-mount.subdir=vardocker /dev/sda3 /var/lib/docker
```

Btrfs subvolumes make it somewhat easier by always having a direct mount option to select the subvolumes; they also have the advantage that snapshots are scoped to a single subvolume, so you can have different snapshot schedules for $HOME vs Docker.

Use `btrfs subvol create` to create subvolumes and the `subvol=` option to select them:

```
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/disk
btrfs subvolume create /mnt/disk/home
btrfs subvolume create /mnt/disk/vardocker
umount /mnt/disk

mount -o subvol=home /dev/sda3 /home
mount -o subvol=vardocker /dev/sda3 /var/lib/docker
```

Subvolumes behave very much like regular subdirectories; they can be created at any depth in the filesystem hierarchy (the full path relative to the filesystem root is specified for `subvol=`).

Comment: Thank you for the great examples and explanation. That's a good idea about the bind mount option; good to know the same strategy can be used for ext4 and other filesystems. And the btrfs approach looks very straightforward too. Yes, the /var/lib/docker is what I intended as well. Thanks again!